# How can I use Q Promise library to possibly flatten and reduce complexity of the snippet below

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, q

I'm new to NodeJS and learning the promise library Q. I recently came up with the horrendous code snippet below. I could not for the life of me figure out how to reduce the complexity of it. I thought using a promise library should help me do this but not sure how to go about it. I've commented where ever I think I need to point out dependencies between each step. Also note that,

1. I'm using the Node Express library and this is a HTTP POST handler
2. The database queries use the node-mysql library
3. I'm using Node with the --harmony flag and targeting ECMA 6
4. The functions retrieveDeliveryAddress and retrieveMarkets return promises themselves

Please help.

```
this.post = function(req, respond){

    var deliveryAddressId = req.body.deliveryAddressId;
    var restaurants = req.body.restaurants;
    var previousToken = req.body.pricingToken;

    //retrieveDeliveryAddress needs to be called initially to validate its existence before running any other queries
    retrieveDeliveryAddress(deliveryAddressId)
        .then(function(deliveryAddress){
            var getConnectionFn = self.q.nbind(self.mainDataConnectionPool.getConnection, self.mainDataConnectionPool);
            getConnectionFn().then((connection) => {
                var retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery = self.config.data.queries.Q0014;
                retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery.values = flattenRestaurantItemChoiceGroups(restaurants);

                var queryFn = self.q.nbind(connection.query, connection);
                queryFn(retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery)
                    .then(() => {
                        //Needs to be executed after the retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery since the next query uses a temp table created by it
                        var retrievePricingItemsQuery = self.config.data.queries.Q0015;
                        retrievePricingItemsQuery.values = [
                            self.config.sap.constants.defaultMandt,
                            self.config.sap.constants.trueFlag
                        ];

                        queryFn(retrievePricingItemsQuery)
                            .then((resultsets) => {
                                var rows = self.helpersUtil.firstSqlResultset(resultsets);
                                if(rows == null) {
                                    throw self.exceptionFac.createInstance('E1006', 409);
                                }

                                var result = {
                                    items: [],
                                    pricingToken: null,
                                    pricingSummary: null
                                }

                                var itemGroups = self.lazy(rows).groupBy(function(x){
                                    return x.RestaurantId + ':' + x.ItemId;
                                }).toArray();


                                //A bunch of other stuff happens here and finally I invoke the response callback with the result                                 
                                result.pricingSummary = calculatePricingSummary(deliveryAddress, result.items);
                                respond(null, result); 

                            }).catch((err) => {
                                respond(err, null);
                                connection.release();
                            }).done();

                    }).catch((err) => {
                        respond(err, null);
                        connection.release();
                    }).done();

            }).catch((err) => {
                respond(err, null);
            }).done();

        }).catch((err) => {
            respond(err, null);
        }).done();
};
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I believe the one above is an automated comment. Please let me know how I can refine this and I will. I included all code since I believe it is necessary to identify dependencies between each step so that others realize some steps may not be able to run in parallel

Comment: [You’re Missing the Point of Promises](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970)

Comment: @Harindaka Do you have any specific problem with this code or you just want the code to be refactored?

Comment: [Rookie mistake #1 when using promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html). You have to ***return*** a promise from a `.then` to be able to make a chain pattern, otherwise you're just creating a callback hell.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this guys. So i need to find how to return a promise from a then using Q  and this should flatten things out. Will try this.

Comment: WTH do you call `retrieveDeliveryAddress(deliveryAddressId)` for? You're never using the `deliveryAddress` value anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi Thankyou for pointing that out. I edited the question to include the usage. Just before the respond callback is called. Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is already in the comments above (@minitech, @laggingreflex), and the referenced articles explain it very well. So this is just an illustration really...

```
retrieveDeliveryAddress(deliveryAddressId)
    .then(function(deliveryAddress){
        var getConnectionFn = self.q.nbind(self.mainDataConnectionPool.getConnection, self.mainDataConnectionPool);
        return getConnectionFn();
    })
    .then((connection) => {
        var retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery = self.config.data.queries.Q0014;
        retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery.values = flattenRestaurantItemChoiceGroups(restaurants);

        var queryFn = self.q.nbind(connection.query, connection);
        return queryFn(retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery).then(() => { return queryFn; });
    })
    .then((queryFn) => {
        //Needs to be executed after the retrievePricingItemsParamsQuery since the next query uses a temp table created by it
        var retrievePricingItemsQuery = self.config.data.queries.Q0015;
        retrievePricingItemsQuery.values = [
            self.config.sap.constants.defaultMandt,
            self.config.sap.constants.trueFlag
        ];

        return queryFn(retrievePricingItemsQuery);
    })
    .then((resultsets) => {
        var rows = self.helpersUtil.firstSqlResultset(resultsets);
        if(rows == null) {
            throw self.exceptionFac.createInstance('E1006', 409);
        }

        var result = {
            items: [],
            pricingToken: null,
            pricingSummary: null
        }

        var itemGroups = self.lazy(rows).groupBy(function(x){
            return x.RestaurantId + ':' + x.ItemId;
        }).toArray();

        //A bunch of other stuff happens here and finally I invoke the response callback with the result

        result.pricingSummary = calculatePricingSummary(deliveryAddress, result.items);
        respond(null, result); 

    }).catch((err) => {
        respond(err, null);
        connection.release();
    }).done();
```

Comment: You are correct. This completes the queston. Thanks